# Error running Kubernetes dashboard locally

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-dashboard

I am on a Mac and trying to run Kubernetes dashboard locally. I have done this before, but now getting error. Following the [instructions](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/access-application-cluster/web-ui-dashboard/) and was doing -

`kubectl apply -f https://raw.githubusercontent.com/kubernetes/dashboard/v2.0.0/aio/deploy/recommended.yaml`

And getting error -

`Error from server (NotFound): the server could not find the requested resource`

My Docker version:

```
Client: Docker Engine - Community
 Version:           19.03.8
 API version:       1.40
 Go version:        go1.12.17
 Git commit:        afacb8b
 Built:             Wed Mar 11 01:21:11 2020
 OS/Arch:           darwin/amd64
 Experimental:      true

Server: Docker Engine - Community
 Engine:
  Version:          19.03.8
  API version:      1.40 (minimum version 1.12)
  Go version:       go1.12.17
  Git commit:       afacb8b
  Built:            Wed Mar 11 01:29:16 2020
  OS/Arch:          linux/amd64
  Experimental:     true
 containerd:
  Version:          v1.2.13
  GitCommit:        7ad184331fa3e55e52b890ea95e65ba581ae3429
 runc:
  Version:          1.0.0-rc10
  GitCommit:        dc9208a3303feef5b3839f4323d9beb36df0a9dd
 docker-init:
  Version:          0.18.0
  GitCommit:        fec3683
 Kubernetes:
  Version:          v1.16.6-beta.0
  StackAPI:         v1alpha3
```

My Kubernetes version -

```
Client Version: version.Info{Major:"1", Minor:"9", GitVersion:"v1.9.4", GitCommit:"bee2d1505c4fe820744d26d41ecd3fdd4a3d6546", GitTreeState:"clean", BuildDate:"2018-03-12T16:29:47Z", GoVersion:"go1.9.3", Compiler:"gc", Platform:"darwin/amd64"}
Server Version: version.Info{Major:"1", Minor:"16+", GitVersion:"v1.16.6-beta.0", GitCommit:"e7f962ba86f4ce7033828210ca3556393c377bcc", GitTreeState:"clean", BuildDate:"2020-01-15T08:18:29Z", GoVersion:"go1.13.5", Compiler:"gc", Platform:"linux/amd64"}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Kubectl client seems too old version(`v1.9.4`) which can't speak to newer Kubernetes clusters(`v1.16.6`). Install latest version of kubectl client on your Mac system following the guide [here](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/tools/install-kubectl/#install-kubectl-on-macos)

Comment: Updated the kubectl client and seems to be working. Thanks a lot.